# WIll my BitLocker work after OS upgrade? If so how?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, bitlocker

Currently working over at Windows 8.1 64 bit, I have protected one of my drives with BitLocker encryption lets say it as "D? and the OS resides at "C",

Now I decide to upgrade OS to Windows 10 64 bit. Will my BitLocker work after OS upgrade. I understand that both OS were at same, but I believe and doubt that OS encryption methodology present at OS part, So my questions were few :

- Will  my BitLocker work after my os upgrade?
- If yes how it will get worked after upgrade since the main key verification part would be done at os part

I don't have any citation that key verification was done at OS drive but requesting clarification to the community.

Comment: Do you have C: encrypted as well, or only D:? In any case, an in-place upgrade should not wipe BL secrets or metadata, so it should work. You may need to suspend BL while doing the upgrade, though.

Comment: @CBHacking only d is encrypted friend

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 What downvoters?